# how to select a tag element based on text of its parent tag

Tags: css, css-selectors

```
<td>
<strong>Modality</strong>
<ul class="field-items list-plain">
<li class="field-item">Loan</li>
</ul>
</td>

<td>
<strong>Sector</strong>
<ul class="field-items list-plain">
      <li class="field-item">Agriculture, natural resources and rural development</li>
</ul>
</td>
```

I want to use a CSS selector to select the only li that is a direct child of a TD tag and its parent td tag has Sector text in it. Basically, I want my second li should be selected.

Comment: _“the only li that is a direct child of a TD tag”_ - there are none of those, in the code you have shown. The LI are children of UL (as they should be); child and descendant are two different things.

Answer (score 2):

Because there are two `<ul>` elements with the class `field-items` and the `<li>` elements are nested inside the `<ul>` you will need to select the correct parent `<ul>` element and then select the `<li>` from there. You can use the `nth-of-type(n)` selector in order to achieve that in this case, if you know that you want to select the 2nd `<li>`.

```css
.field-items:nth-of-type(2) .field-item {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<td>
<strong>Modality</strong>
<ul class="field-items list-plain">
<li class="field-item">Loan</li>
</ul>
</td>

<td>
<strong>Sector</strong>
<ul class="field-items list-plain">
      <li class="field-item">Agriculture, natural resources and rural development</li>
</ul>
</td>
```

**However**, you cannot retrieve a specific element basing on it's text content using plain CSS, you will need to have some Javascript code that does that for you. **Like this:**

```js
document.querySelectorAll("strong").forEach((el) => {
  if (el.textContent === "Sector") {
    el.closest("td").querySelector(".field-item").style.color = 'red';
  }
});
```

```html
<table>
<td>
<strong>Modality</strong>
<ul class="field-items list-plain">
<li class="field-item">Loan</li>
</ul>
</td>

<td>
<strong>Sector</strong>
<ul class="field-items list-plain">
      <li class="field-item">Agriculture, natural resources and rural development</li>
</ul>
</td>
</table>
```

Comment: i copied only two of them, there are many tds and you don't know exactly how many would be.

Comment: If the content is dynamic or you have multiple `<td>` elements that can have the text `Sector` inside them, you will need to use Javascript to retrieve them. It is not possible to select basing on text content using vanilla CSS. If you want, I can write some JavaScript code and update my answer with that, let me know if you want that.

Comment: I've updated my answer to also include the Javascript code to achieve that.

Comment: Thank you Link, I appreciate your help